# Integral Contour

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

i have an integral to solve:
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty v^2 \frac{e^{-i\omega\tau}}{\omega^2-k^2v^2}d\omega$

I got solution $\frac{\pi v}{k} \sin(kv\tau)$, but in a book the solution was $\frac{2\pi v}{k} \sin (kv\tau)$, why i got answer only half of the true answer?
[Here is my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoKsz.png)

[and this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyBpF.png)

and this is what i got from some books that the answer was twice from my answer:[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTJcS.png)

did i make a mistake?

Comment: but, my answer was a half from the books answer

Comment: no..noo.. almost all the books say like that

Answer (score 1):

There is a variant of the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) that states if a singularity is actually on the contour instead of inside it, it's residue is counted at half value (See, for example, George Arfken's "Mathematical Methods for Physicists", Section 7.2). Setting $$f(z) = v^2\dfrac{e^{-iz\tau}}{z^2-k^2v^2}$$, the residues are
$$R(f,kv) = \lim_{z\to kv}(z - kv)f(z) = \lim_{z\to kv}\dfrac{e^{-iz\tau}}{z+kv} = \dfrac{e^{-ikv\tau}}{2kv}$$
and similarly
$$R(f,-kv) = -\dfrac{e^{ikv\tau}}{2kv}$$

So by the Residue theorem and noting that the integral around the top arc $\to 0$ as the radius $\to \infty$, the Residue theorem says

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty v^2f(z)dz &= v^2\pi i(R(f,-kv)+R(f,kv))\\
&=v^2\pi i\left(\dfrac{e^{-ikv\tau}}{2kv}-\dfrac{e^{ikv\tau}}{2kv}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi v}k\sin{kv\tau}\end{align}$$

So the answer is: you are not wrong, the book is. That quote you included from another book doesn't even make sense. It says $C$ is "chosen as a closed path" to "avoid those poles". But it is claiming an integral on the real line which *must* pass through those poles. I'm guessing your books are copying from a single source who made the error and the copiers, already being aware of the basic concepts, never bothered to double check it themselves (or in the case of the quote, gave a vague hand-wavy explanation without bothering to think much about it).

Comment: Isnt the integral value = 2pi i* Residue  not pi i* Residue?

Comment: No. As I discussed in the opening paragraph, $2\pi iR$ is what you get for residues in the interior of the contour. But residues on the contour itself only contribute half as much, so only $\pi iR$.

Comment: What of the contour like this?

Comment: https://ibb.co/w41Kx5Z

Comment: Then you don't get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty v^2f(z)dz$. Instead you get $-\int_{-\infty}^\infty v^2f(z+\epsilon i)dz$ ("$-$" because you've chosen a clockwise path instead of counterclockwise). If you can prove that the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ of that integral converges to the integral along the real line, fine. But both your and my calculations are that it does not.